# Serving maintenance page with 503 status code in Caddy

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I'm trying to do something which seems fairly trivial to me, but can't seem to get it right with Caddy.

I have the following site configured with Caddy:

```
foo.com {
  tls {
    dns cloudflare ...
  }
  reverse_proxy /* http://proxy-foo
}
```

I'm now trying to enable a maintenance page, such that all requests serve the maintenance html, and return a 503 status code. But, I can either serve the page, or the status code, but not both.

I first tried the `handle_errors` directive, with a respond directive

```
foo.com {
  tls {
    dns cloudflare ...
  }
  # reverse_proxy /* http://proxy-foo
  handle_errors {
    rewrite * /503.html
    file_server
  }
  respond * 503
}
```

only to later read the caveat that respond doesn't trigger the error handlers.

Also tried removing all other directives, thinking that would trigger a 404, which would in turn call the handle_errors block, but that too doesn't work. It just ends up returning 200, but with no body.

Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try configure [reverse_proxy](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy) directive.

That code similar to docs example is worked for me:

```
:80

reverse_proxy localhost:8000 {
    @error status 500 503
    handle_response @error {
        respond "Something bad happened. If the error occurs again, please contact me at example@mail.com"
        # i guess we can use other directives like redirect 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently caddy can create a `matchers` logic for a [file](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/matchers#file) like so:

```
@hasMaintenance file /path/to/your/maintenance_file.html
handle @hasMaintenance {
    try_files /path/to/your/maintenance_file.html
    file_server {
        status 503
    }
}
```

This only returns the maintenance file with a 503 status code, if it is found by the matcher. Otherwise continue as usual.

Comment: How do you include that in your Caddyfile? In each domain block? How does it bypass normal server operation for each domain?